# Linear Programming - Overtime restriction

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

hopefully I can get some help on this problem, it's got me quite stumped.

I was given a linear programming problem with the goal of minimizing labor costs. The variables x_t represent the number of workers available in month t (t = 1, 2, ..., 12), while o_t represents how many of the workers can work overtime hours in month t. The problem has two constraints on overtime:

"Overtime may not exceed 10% of straight time production in any month, and overtime may not be scheduled for more than two consecutive months."

I've got the 10% restriction done, but I absolutely cannot figure out how to make the constraint for consecutive months. I have a feeling that I need to use binary variables, i.e., if y_t represents whether or not overtime was activated in month t (t = 3, ... 12), and y_t is either 0 or 1, then y_t-2 + y_t-1 + y_t ≤ 2. But I can't figure out how to tie this into my overtime constraint.

I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

EDIT:

Right now my 10% constraint is: o_t ≤ 0.1*x_t for t = 1, 2, ..., 12

Comment: What's your 10% constraint?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I apologize since I didn't phrase that correctly. What I meant was, I do not know how to correlate the y_i variables to my overtime variables. So, if overtime for any workers was scheduled for month 5, how does y_5 get set to 1? It's been years since I've done LP, so this may be obvious but I'm just not seeing it. Thank you.

Comment: ok- I need to think about that

Comment: See my answer @RLS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an if/then constraint, which is if '$O_t \gt 0$ then $y_t = 1$'.

If P then Q is equivalent to (not P) or Q and so we have

$O_t \le 0$ or $y_t = 1$.

Why not $O_t = 0$ instead of $O_t \le 0$?

We will need to add the constraint $O_t \ge 0$ anyway, so this is covered.  Later on it will become clear (Godwilling) why we use $O_t \le 0$ rather than $O_t = 0$.

The standard way of dealing with an either X or Y constraint like this (where X and Y are constraints involving integer variables) is to add these 2 constraints:

$O_t \le M_1 \delta$ (where $\delta $ is a binary variable and we choose the constant $M_1$ according to the problem after thinking about it).

$-y_t \le \ M_2(1-\delta)$ (however, since $y_t$ is a binary rather than an integer variable, it's necessary to adapt the method at this point to fit the problem). Since the only possible values for $y_t$ are 0 and 1, why not just try the following:

$y_t = \delta$.

If $\delta = 0$, $O_t \le 0$ (from constraint 1) and so $O_t = 0$ (from non-negativity contraint).

$\delta = 0$ sets $y_t$ to $0$ in the second constraint.

If $\delta = 1$, the first constraint becomes $O_t \le M_1$. What should we choose $M_1$ to be?  So as to allow our solution method to consider all possible values of $O_t$ and choose the optimal one, choose $M_1$ to be 0.1 $\times S_t$, where $S_t$ is the value of the straight time production for month t.

$\delta = 1$ sets $y_t$ to 1 as well, as required.

At this point, I realised that since the second constraint tell us that $y_t = \delta$, we don't really need it. We can just replace the binary variable $\delta $ by $y_t$ itself and have just the first constraint (changing $M_1$ to $M$):

$O_t \le My_t$ where M = 0.1 $\times$ straight time production for month t.

The method you use to solve it will now be able to compare the following 2 possibilites and find which produces the optimal solution.  To be rigorous, let's just make sure the constraints are all covered:

case 1: $y_t = 0$

Since $y_t$ = 0, we need $O_t = 0$ which it is when $y_t = 0$ is substituted into $O_t \le My_t$.

case 1: $y_t = 1$

Now we just need $O_t \le 0.1S_t$, precisely what we get by substituting $y_t = 1$ into the constraint.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: No probs: I've just added a lengthy explanation of how I worked this out which is almost finished.  (Don't feel obliged to read it, but's it's there if you need it).

Comment: Very good explanation, thank you for taking the time to write it all out. Everything makes sense!

Comment: No probs: actually, I've thought of some improvements I could make to the explanation to make it clearer, but I haven't done anything about it yet.

Comment: Just made the edits. This could be the final draft!

Comment: There were loads of errors (mainly typos) but 2 big ones. I guess you may have noticed them. I said at points to take $M = S_t$ where $S_t$ is straight time production. It should have been $M = 0.1S_t$. Also, I said that M could just be a big constant instead, but that's not true in this problem, since the problem states $O_t \le 0.1S_t$. I've edited the answer accordingly.